# How to generate POJO for global element using JAXB (xjc)?

Tags: java, xsd

Is there anyway to get a POJO generated for the "status" element shown below? ObjectFactory have a function for marshalling the element, but how do you unmarshal it without a "status.class" to use with AXBContext.newInstance ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    version="1.0">        
<xs:element name="status" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include the `ObjectFactory` in the array of classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

Or create the `JAXBContext` on the package name of the generated classes:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.model");
```